# 240 AC Voltage into a 120 to 240 transformer

Tags: transformer

I have a transformer that can switch between step-up and step-down with a switch and I accidentally set it to step-up instead of step-down and plugged it into a 240 volts outlet and it buzzed and stopped working. did I kill it or do I need to replace a fuse? on the back it has a fuse that you can remove.

Comment: Why not extract the fuse and check if it is burnt out?

Comment: *Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired.*

Comment: Sounds like a fuse or circuit breaker somewhere tripped. That doesn't mean your device was NOT damaged. But there is hope. Now you just have to try to find the fuse or breaker and see if you can replace it.

Answer (score 1):

If you connected 240 V into a transformer winding rated 120 V, the core would have saturated and the winding drawn a very large current, which would have taken out any reasonable value fuse upstream.

If you have a fuse upstream of it, congratulations, it's saved your transformer from any overheating damage. Replace the fuse with another fuse of the same value.

The transformer may have produced a large voltage on the secondary. If this transformer was intended for mains use, then it will have been designed to withstand transients of at least 1500 V, which are common in mains distribution systems. It's unlikely the transformer will have suffered any insulation breakdown damage.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say, as other have commented. If it was for a *really* short period, the buzzing was only indicating a core saturation. After that a transformer overheats and loses insulation, usually.

A continuity check on the primary would be the first thing to do to verify the status of primary protection (fuses or thermals); after that check the other winding for plausible resistance values (if you have some ideas).

If the equipment is available then check winding insulation to the ground; quite important for safety!

If everything passes, *very cautiously* power up the transformer unloaded, then verify the outpus. In case of doubt junk it :D

Answer (score -1):

Without any data sheets or photos, it's hard to tell. If you plugged it into 240 volts and it was set to step up, then it would have tried to output 480 volts. This undoubtedly exceeded its design ratings. I assume there was no load attached because you probably would have blown any. If there is a fuse, then, indeed, you should check the fuse and replace it if blown. Then try the transformer again with the proper connections. If it works, you are good to go. If not then the transformer is damaged